# Inexpensive way of connecting a lot of modules on a distance

Tags: i2c, nrf24l01+, wireless, wires

I need to connect a lot (~100) of modules with a computer (Raspberry pi). The modules are based on Arduino micro and are very simple. They will be spread around, but for the two adjacent the distance would not be larger than 2 meters.
From time to time they receive information from the computer and also can send some data back. So bandwidth requirement is small.

My first idea was connecting them in one i2c network. It would be fine, except I have figured out that i2c is not good for a distances. Signal degrades and communication is unreliable if works in the first place.

Second idea is the nrf24 network (mash). But I am not sure how reliable communication is with them? Wired seams more reliable.

What would you recommend? It needs to be as cheap as possible, because of number of modules. Reliability of communication is important. The bandwidth requirement is very small (1Kbps is enough). Also modules are not battery powered so no need to be low power option.

What is the best way of doing this?

EDIT:
Network topology (it can be changed):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgY4Uu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I don't think I2C will necessarily be bad. You'd have to be a bit more considerate in applying it; like spreading the pull-up resistors and picking the correct values, and maybe do some termination to prevent ringing. Lowering the clock speed will also help. But I'm no expert here. You could [read this paper](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10658.pdf). The first alternative to sprung to mind was RS485, which is pretty robust. PS what is the total length? Also how are they connected? All in a single line, or more like a tree?

Comment: There are *lots* of ways of doing that.  Wired can work if you do a daisy chain rather than a bus, but you do have to deal with wires.  Radio works too if you design your protocol well - you can get modules on-air compatible with the NRF24L01 for a dollar each.  You haven't specified the maximum distance from the pi to a node; if it is beyond expected radio range you do a mesh or forwarding scheme, at the cost of software complexity.  At a higher radio cost (~$10 in small quantities) there are also things like LoRa.

Comment: Yes, probably I2C could work, but still I am afraid it would be pretty unreliable. Or maybe I am too afraid. Maximum length is ~50m, so mesh would be needed. They would be connected like multiple rows connected in column (something like stretched star). Hope you understand. RS485 is only between two modules, no network? Need to daisy chain? I will read about it. LoRa looks too expensive (if could be avoided).

Comment: Added picture of network topology. Number of modules is larger, but this is basic idea.

Comment: Looks like RS485 is a good solution for wired communication over some distance. Which would you prefer nRf24 vs RS485?

Comment: nRF24-s are probably cheaper and easier to use than RS485 system.

Comment: What about reliability? Can nRf24 be sufficiently reliable. Do you have any experience with it?